# Fetch Data from Url Using java

Tags: java, url, jsoup

This question was asked me during my interview, and i was asked to implement it. The question is as follows:

Your application

1. Will take the username and password for the linkedIn profile,
2. On the page www.linkedin.com , use that to login into the page.
3. Simulate the Clicking of the Profile->Edit profile menu
4. Scrape the page of that user that comes below in the format below and dumps it in a text file. ( hint: you can use the beautiful soup library )

On fetching this url, you need to read the following information and put it in an csv/excel  file.

Can somebody give me an idea on how to do it? It should be done using java only.

Comment: In such a case you don't have to provide a solution if you don't know one, but just to give hints about to way you will tackle the problem. You can say that there is probably automation software for this, but if you would implement it by yourself then you can suggest to examine if there exists an api, if not examine the url scheme, the code source of the pages, etc. An interview is not an academic examination. Dev recruiters look for people having something to say and try facing a problem.

Comment: And sometimes recruiters have no clue what the dev dept actually is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Web Browser Automation software like Selenium http://www.seleniumhq.org/ which seems like will solve this problem. You can choose any of its bindings (Java, C#, Ruby, Python, JavaScript) to implement the solution.

Take a look at the tutorials https://www.airpair.com/selenium/posts/selenium-tutorial-with-java

Answer (score 0):

It seems related to web crawler, and we can do this using JSOUP library very well.
You have to read implementation using JSOUP library and we can filter out the link which has something like

> https://www.linkedin.com/profile/edit?trk=nav_responsive_sub_nav_edit_profile"

Here if you see we are having the keywords as edit_profile which can be used to filter out the results we require.

Link u should follow and explore more about JSOUP
[Webcrawler using JSOUP](http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-make-a-simple-web-crawler-in-java/)